# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser at runtime when trying to parse json

Tags: java, json, gwt, runtime-error

I'm working with GWT and I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONParser` Exception at runtime when I try to parse JSON.

I've imported the following:
`import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser;`

My code is

```
String r = ((Text) Entity.getProperty("result")).getValue();    
JSONValue jsonValue;
jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(r);
```

Generally I would say that the jar couldn't be found, but in that case no external jar is needed, right? So what is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To work with JSON, you need to inherit the right module (in your application module).

```xml
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.json.JSON'/>
```

Also, be sure to have `gwt-user.jar` in your classpath.